# Is it possible to have .htaccess rules for a specific domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, add-type

Is there a way of having an `AddType` command only apply on certain hosts?

Specifically: `AddType x-httpd-php54 .php`

There's a lot of questions about having different `RewriteRule` definitions for different domains and you can do that with `RewriteCond` but is there an equivalent for non-rewrite related stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use [`T`  flag of `mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_t) like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)somdomain\. [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [T=application/x-httpd-php54]
```

Comment: Should that be `RewriteRule \.php$ - [T=application/x-httpd-php54]`?

Comment: Yes definitely it should be set for `.php` files only. Fixed and sorry I had missed it.

Comment: That was quick! I'm afraid it doesn't work though :(

Comment: You mean it was working without `.php` but doesn't work any more?

Comment: I was a bit premature with my upvote and acceptance, it's not worked in either case

Comment: By testing whether or not the `AddType` rule has been added with the domain specific code, and with the generic code

Comment: That is what I wanted to know how did you test/verify? Since it worked in my testing.